# How to delay a LIVE broadcast

Tags: icecast

First I can't find anything about this online and I am sure that no one would ever want this however, I do require this.

I am looking for away to take my live Icecast stream and delay it based on the users time zone.

I am not wanting to do all time zones just the following. NOTE: We are based on the **AWST (UTC +8)**  time zone.

Timezone I need my station to be delayed for:
Sydney Australia (AEDT (UTC +11) )
Washington, USA (UTC -5)
New York (UTC -5)

Now I because this is a LIVE broadcast that we need to delay. i am unsure where to start. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Audio online, or video as well?  Is this is fixed delay, as in a constant stream that's always delayed?  Or will you be controlling playout on the delay end?  There are a lot of solutions, from letting FFmpeg buffer it, to writing it out to disk as HLS and using a regular HLS Player to playback.  Or, something custom as well.  More details would help us point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Brad audio only LIVE icecast stream

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make 3 different mountpoints, one for each timezone (like *//server:8000/live-AWST*, *//server:8000/live-AEDT*, etc.).

Start your live source 13 hours (8+5) earlier and send it to UTC-5 mountpoints and record it to the file.
Then, at expected time, send this recording to UTC+8 mountpoint and after 3h (11-8) send it to the UTC+11 mountpoint.

Other solution can use dedicated client (player) that implements the delay.